# using division to select all elements in mysql

Tags: mysql

A food can be Simple or Agregate.. if its simples it has a type.. if agregate it has a composition of simples foods
I need to create a query to select all restaurants that sold all agregate dishes that has food type=meat. I try a lot of things but i cant reach the problem.

```
    create table Restaurant(
        nameR VARCHAR(80),
        primary key (nameR));

    create table Sold(
        nameF VARCHAR(80),
        nameR VARCHAR(80),
        date VARCHAR(20);
        constraint c3 primary key(nameF,nameR,date),
        foreign key(nameF) references Dish(nameF),
        foreign key(nameR) references Restaurante(nameR),
        foreign key(date) references Data(date));

    create table Dishe(
        nameF VARCHAR(80),
        primary key (nameF),
        foreign key (nameF) references Food(nameF));

   create table Simple( 
       nameF VARCHAR(80), 
      type VARCHAR(80),
      primary key (nameF), 
       foreign key (nameF) references Food(nameF));

    create table Agregate(
       nameF VARCHAR(80),
       calorias double,
       primary key (nameF),
       foreign key (nameF) references Food(nameF));

    create table Composition(
       nameAgg VARCHAR(80),
        nameS VARCHAR(80),
        quantidade integer,
       constraint c1 primary key(nameAgg,nameS),
       foreign key(nameAgg) references Agregate(nameF),
      foreign key(nameS) references Simple(nameF));

    create table Food( 
         nameF varchar(80)
         primary key (nameF));
```

I think that i should use division right? tell me what you think

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL has some syntax errors in, also it references a Data table in the foreign key of "Sold" and I'm not sure why the "Dishe" table exists - it seems to just store the same data as Food?

Anyway, here's corrected SQL for creating the tables:

```
create table Restaurant(
    nameR VARCHAR(80),
    primary key (nameR)
);

create table Food( 
    nameF varchar(80), 
    type varchar(80),
    primary key (nameF)
);

create table Dishe(
    nameF VARCHAR(80),
    primary key (nameF),
    foreign key (nameF) references Food(nameF)
);

create table Sold(
    nameF VARCHAR(80),
    nameR VARCHAR(80),
    date VARCHAR(20),
    constraint c3 primary key(nameF,nameR,date),
    foreign key(nameF) references Dishe(nameF),
    foreign key(nameR) references Restaurant(nameR)
);
```

We can insert some test data:

```
INSERT INTO Restaurant (nameR) VALUES ('McDonalds');
INSERT INTO Restaurant (nameR) VALUES ('Vital Ingredient');
INSERT INTO Restaurant (nameR) VALUES ('David Food');
INSERT INTO Food (nameF, type) VALUES ('Burger', 'meat');
INSERT INTO Food (nameF, type) VALUES ('Salad', 'veg');
INSERT INTO Dishe (nameF) VALUES ('Burger');
INSERT INTO Dishe (nameF) VALUES ('Salad');
INSERT INTO Sold VALUES ('Salad', 'David Food', '2013-12-05');
INSERT INTO Sold VALUES ('Burger', 'McDonalds', '2013-12-04');
INSERT INTO Sold VALUES ('Burger', 'McDonalds', '2013-12-05');
INSERT INTO Sold VALUES ('Burger', 'Vital Ingredient', '2013-12-05');
INSERT INTO Sold VALUES ('Salad', 'Vital Ingredient', '2013-12-04');
```

This creates three restaurants, only one restaurant has sold only meat dishes.

There are two methods which I can think of which will return the restaurants which have sold all meat dishes. The first one doesn't use division - it uses the GROUP_CONCAT function to stick all the types of dishes served by each restaurant together and see if this equals "meat":

```
SELECT 
    Sold.nameR
FROM
    Sold
INNER JOIN
    Food
ON
    Food.nameF = Sold.nameF
GROUP BY 
    Sold.nameR
HAVING
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Food.type) = 'meat'
;
```

The second one uses division to count the number of meat dishes sold by each restaurant and dividing this by the total number of dishes served and checking if this equals 1 - i.e. 100% of dishes served were meat. This method is likely to be slower than the one above because of the subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    Restaurant.nameR
FROM
    Restaurant
WHERE
    (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        Sold 
    INNER JOIN 
        Food 
    ON 
        Food.nameF = Sold.nameF 
    WHERE 
        Food.type = 'meat' 
    AND 
        Sold.nameR = Restaurant.nameR 
    ) / (
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        Sold 
    INNER JOIN 
        Food 
    ON 
        Food.nameF = Sold.nameF 
    WHERE 
        Sold.nameR = Restaurant.nameR 
    ) = 1
;
```

Comment: your query select Restaurants that sold 1+ dishes type = meat.. i want to select restaurants that sol all dishes with type meat..

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your requirement - I will change the answer.

Comment: @user3046650 - I updated my answer, please let me know if this is the result you were expecting. Thanks.

Comment: at this moment, my mysql server is offline and i dont know why, so i cant try your answer.. but as soon as possible i will make it ;)

Comment: Hi @user3046650, I setup a quick SQL fiddle to demo it so you can test out the queries - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d1ae/1

Comment: there must me one problem because the last query return 2 results from  200 rows.. but one is right and the other not xd i dont know where is the problem..
i found the solution trying some things xd thanks for the help

Comment: Which of the queries returned 2 rows? Happy to change my answer for history's sake - so that anyone stumbling across the page with the same problem has the solution.

Comment: i've updated my code and now that are the final tables.. sorry for this mess.. can you help me again?